# Java nested if-statement vs if-else

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

I'm not sure which of the following code snippets I should prefer.

A) Nested

```
if(cond1 != null) {
    if(cond2 != null) {
        //Do the good stuff here
    } else {
        System.out.println("Sorry cond2 was null");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry cond1 was null");
}
```

B) Flat

```
if(cond1 == null) {
    System.out.println("Sorry cond1 was null");
} else if(cond2 == null) {
    System.out.println("Sorry cond2 was null");
} else {
    //Do the good stuff
}
```

I think B is more readable. But what is more Java-like?

Comment: Both equally valid. I agree the second is more readable.

Comment: both are "java-like", but if you might also want to consider a single  `if(cond1 == null || cond2==null) {} else {}`

Comment: use nested statements only whenever you need them.There's no use of making a simpler program complex.Nestedness increases the complexity of understanding the program and may cause errors in your program.However it can also be a useful tool while writing complex programs.If you are a beginner learn the usefulness of nested programs and for the time being write **Flat**

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I need to display a custom message depending on which argument is null so I think I have to stick with two conditions...
Otherwise I would agree =)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [codereview.se]

Comment: @JiriTousek "Please do not vote to close with a custom reason that 'it belongs on Code Review'. Nothing in the Stack Overflow rules justifies such a custom reason, and sloppy reasoning perpetuates inappropriate referrals. Not all questions about analyzing code are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and not all code review requests are on-topic on Code Review. Instead, vote to close as too broad or primarily opinion-based". See [the CR guide for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @Zeta Noted, thanks.

Comment: @Zeta so where should I ask such a question next time?

Comment: Why "sorry" before the "condX is null"? Is it such a bad thing that anyone should feel sorry about that?

Comment: Neither of your examples is correct. See my answer and mirabilos's answer to this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/240568/should-i-follow-the-normal-path-or-fail-early/240626#240626

Comment: @JackAidley there are situations when approach B is desired

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second one, `if-then-else` is both more readable and used in the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html.

This might depend on your project's code convention but deep code nesting should be avoided as it's unreadable. Introducing a superficial nested `if` statement instead of `if-then-else` would be discouraged.

Your particular example looks like preconditions which are generally easier to write with [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-):

```
Objects.requireNonNull(cond1);
Objects.requireNonNull(cond2);
//Do the good stuff
```

Comment: Great advise to use `Objects.requireNonNull()` didn't know that! Thanks.

Comment: Do note that you can use them in constructors like `this.fieldA = Objects.requireNonNull(fieldA);`

Answer (score 6):

Considering [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) you should use the least nested option possible. That said, it is also a good idea to go with the things that are more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for **approach B**

I usually prefer to handle negative cases first, and then handle positive cases.

**Example:**

```
public String doWork(String arg1, String arg2)
{
    if(arg1 == null || arg2 == null)
    {
        // do stuff
        return null; // if you wish to...
    }

    // do important stuff
}
```

**General Note:**

I always go for the approach that is more readable/understandable.

As Joshua Bloch says, write code that clearly works rather than code that merely works (anyone reading your code later would be eternally grateful).

Performance hit is negligible, I even wonder if there is a performance hit at all at **runtime**, because nowadays, compilers do a pretty good job at optimizing the code.